# Post two lists to Wordpress at the same time

Tags: python, wordpress, python-3.x, iframe

I started learning python a bit over a week now and i'm stuck on a small project that i've been working on .....

I created a script that would scrape a site for some content(post titles, urls)... Then post these things to Wordpress using the WP API....

Everything was moving smoothly till I ran into a roadblock that I couldn't figure out...

```
    import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import io
import time
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc import *
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import media, posts
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods.posts import GetPosts, NewPost

modified_lines = []

    #Function pulls all the post Titles and saves it in a txt file called "posts"
def get_posts(pageurl):
    SoupRequest(pageurl)
    with io.open('posts.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') as logfile:
           for posts in soup.findAll('header',{"class":"entry-header"}):
               whatamidoing = (posts.find('a').text)
               ithinkiknow = str(whatamidoing)
               logfile.write(ithinkiknow +"\n")

get_posts("link")

with open('posts.txt') as f:
    scrubbed = list(map(replace_symbols, f.readlines()))


#Function that gets the link of each post on wordpress homepage
def get_posturl(pageurl):
    SoupRequest(pageurl)
    links = soup.findAll('h2',{"class":"entry-title"})
    for l in links:
        global postlink
        postlink = l.find('a')['href']
        modified_line = postlink
        modified_lines.append(modified_line)

get_posturl('link')

#Function to pull Iframes from post
def get_iframe(pageurl):
    for url in pageurl:
        file_name = url.replace('https://', '').replace('.', '_').replace('/','_')
        SoupRequest(url)
        global iframexx
        iframexx = (soup.find_all('iframe'))
get_iframe(modified_lines)


#Function to Post to Wordpress
def post_to_wordpress(title, allVideoLinks):
    tags = []

    wp = Client(wordpressxml, 'USERNAME', 'Password')


    wp.call(GetPosts())

    title = str(title)
    content = str(allVideoLinks)
    post = WordPressPost()
    post.title = title
    post.content = content


    post.post_type = "post"
    post.post_status = 'publish'
    post.id = wp.call(NewPost(post))
    wp.call(posts.EditPost(post.id, post))

for i in scrubbed:
    post_to_wordpress(i,iframexx)
 #Successfully makes posts containing all the different titles....however, each post has the same last iframe link???
```

I put the relevant parts of the code in that paste bin and commented what each function does, or was supposed to do..
.
While it does loop through and make posts containing all the titles from 'scrubbed' , it doesn't do the same for the iframe links. Instead, all the posts have the same iframe post content (The last thing in the list)

Why is this happening? would be eternally grateful if someone assist me

Edit: For further clarification, What I want is to create multiple posts with the titles from(scrubbed) , and the content from(iframexx)

***post1
title: title1

### url: content1

post2
title: title2

### url: content2

post3
title: title3
url: content3***

Also , Side note , why are my Iframes printing out covered with a [ and ]